# How to perform Firebase scheduled function only if value from realtime database is equal X?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm starting my adventure with Firebase cloud functions in my adnroid app in Android Studio and I have no experience with it. What is more I have never used javascript before so everything seems to be new for me. I would like to know if I can make a scheduled function that works like this :

1. At first function checks if value from realtime databse isn't zero.
2. If not, function checks if another value from realtime database is not bigger than 7.
3. If not, the value in database is increased by 1.
4. And then the notification is send.

I made test function to check if data from database are taken corectly but it execute with error "Firebase is not defined".

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
var user = user.uid;
var myRef = firebase.database().ref(user + "/CurrentChallenge/numOfActiveChallenge");
myRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In a Cloud Function, if you want to interact with the Firebase services, you need to use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin).

Also, if you want to read a database node in a Cloud Function, it is more appropriate to read once the node (with `get()` or `once()`) instead of setting a listener with `on()`. As a matter of fact the CF has a short life time and setting a listener is therefore not the correct approach.

It is nor clear how you get the value of the `user` variable. There is no user in a Scheduled Cloud Function. You need to adapt this line, because, as such it will not work.

Finally, it is important to note that you need to terminate a Cloud Function when all the asynchronous work is completed, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions). In the case of a background triggered Cloud Function (e.g. a Pub/Sub schedules Cloud Function) you must return the entire chain of promises returned by the asynchronous method calls. Another possibility is to use async/await, as shown below, and return a value (e.g. `null`) when all the asynchronous work is completed.

So, the following code skeleton should do the trick:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {

    var user = ... // Set the value of user

    const db = admin.database();  // Admin SDK

    const snapshot1 = await db.database().ref("...").get();

    if (snapshot1.val() !== 0) {
        const snapshot2 = await db.database().ref("...").get();

        if (snapshot2.val() <= 7) {

            await db.ref("...").update({
                fieldName: firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1)
            });

            //send the notification
            // See https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js 
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    } else {
        return null;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloud functions are secure environment just like any server. Generally you use the Firebase Admin SDK when using Firebase in Cloud functions or your own servers. To add firebase admin, open terminal and go to the function directory and run the following command:

```
npm install firebase-admin
```

The important thing to note is admin sdk doesn't obey any database security rules as the name says. It has privileged access.

You can try the following code.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin")

admin.initializeApp()

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {
  const myRef1Value = (await admin.database().ref("path/to/resoures").once("value")).val()
  if (myRef1Value > 0) {
    //make another request 
  }
}
```

Similarly make multiple requests as needed (sorry for throwing bunch of JS concepts but feel free to ask any queries)

Another thing I noticed is you are trying to get user ID in it. Scheduled Cloud Functions are not invoked by any user so you can't get any UID in that Cloud function. Can you clarify what is your use case so we can figure out a work around for this?

But what you want to achieve is simple chain if else statements and doing stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) ! Let's clarify the case of using UID -at the time of registration to my app all users are given the same dataset that are updated in time of using the app. So the first parent is user id. So to get to the children I has to first get the UID and thats the reason.

Comment: My app contains 10 challenges that last one week each. Every day user needs to make a summary of the day. In the database there is a "table" that hold the number of active challenge and tha challenge day. I want to use scheduled cloud function to daily increase the day of challenge but only if there is any active challenge and only if the number of day is not higher than 7.  I have no idea how to make it.. I couldn't find any apropreate solution :(

Comment: @rockercarared first things first, you cannot get UID of any user in a scheduled cloud function. But what you can do it do that specific action for all users in that.

Comment: Ok, I understand but do you know any other way to make some activies but only for specyfic users?

Comment: @rockercarared easiest way would be doing this when a user opens your app. Then use [Firebase Callable Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). Here you can check which user actually invoked the functions `(context.auth.uid)` . You can verify it in function if the action has already been processed for that user.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to import and initialize the Firebase Admin SDK as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app):

```
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the database
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

With that, you can then use it with:

```
var myRef = admin.database().ref(user + "/CurrentChallenge/numOfActiveChallenge");
myRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
  ...
```